# Update Pass in Passbook with PHP

Tags: php, passbook

Is it possible to update a Pass in Passbook using PHP? Does anyone has example code or a tutorial? I searched already Google, but can't find anything.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I search for an sample. I can make passes with PHP, but don't know how to begin to make a PHP script to update that pass

Comment: Don't down vote the guy. This is a valid question

Comment: @ChrisB: it is a valid question, but downvotes are sometimes for lack of prior effort. True, he has searched Google, but we get a _lot_ of people here claiming to have searched, only to find that what they need is the first or second search engine result `:)`. Anyway, don't worry about votes too much: the important thing is whether the OP gets their answer.

Comment: @halfer true, just don't want to discourage him - being that he is a fairly new user.

Comment: Passbook is an eco system.  You'll need to build a web service, APNS server, a database to hold live passes and device tokens, and code to dynamically generate and sign the updated pass bundles.  I assume that you have an iOS Apple developer account, if not you'll need one of these as well to obtain the certificate you need to sign the passes you create.  Apple provide a Ruby example server that does pretty much all of this, you can get if from the resources Jordan has posed below.  While it's not PHP, it's relatively simple, well commented code and easy enough to port to PHP.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question, yes. You can use PHP (for the server side component) to update passes.

Start with reading the [Passbook Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/PassKit_PG/Chapters/Introduction.html) from Apple. Then, check out [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20734/beginning-passbook-part-1) tutorial (Which is really good, gives Obj-C Code code samples and explains server side code as well) for integrating and updating Passes in your app.